# Как в smarty сложить значения переменных?

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

Есть код вывода итоговой цены в корзине:

```
<span class="ty-cart-statistic__total-value">
{include file="common/price.tpl"
value=$_total|default:$smarty.capture._total|default:$cart.total 
span_id="cart_total" class="ty-price"}</span>
```

В этот спан нужно добавить код цены залога:

```
<div class="ty-cart-content__sku ty-sku 
cm-hidden-wrapper{if !$product.product_code} hidden{/if}" id="sku_{$key}">{__("sku")}: 
<span class="cm-reload-{$obj_id}" id="product_code_update_{$obj_id}">
{$product.product_code}<!--product_code_update_{$obj_id}--></span>
 </div>
```

`{$product.product_code}` - это цена залога. Но эти блоки находятся в разных файлах, движок `cs cart`.

Comment: суть вопроса не ясна. отредактируйте файл да добавьте искомое значение куда надо. в чем конкретно проблема то?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас есть итоговая цена (первый блок) по всем товарам. И есть `{$product.product_code}` - разный для каждого товара. Похоже `{$product.product_code}` надо просуммировать, и уже затем передать в `smarty` для вывода.

Comment: Все верно, только не понятно как просумировать, сейчас все работает если один товар в корзине.Сделал так: розница + залог, но проблема появляется если добавить в корзину еще товары с залогом, получается что розница добавляет только последний залог а не все залоги сумирует и добавляет к сумме розницы

Comment: value=$_total|default:$smarty.capture._total|default:$cart.total+$product.product_code  сделал так